# How to compute the ifft of a vector?

Tags: polynomials, fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

In the following post [Concrete polynomial implementation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764727/concrete-fft-polynomial-multiplication-example) it is said that the final step before obtaining the product of two polynomials is to compute the ifft of a vector.

How to compute the ifft of a vector for [that example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764727/concrete-fft-polynomial-multiplication-example) ?