# Matrix multiplication using fft

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fast-fourier-transform

Some weeks ago I was thinking about matrix multiplication and fft 
the  complexity of polynomial multiplication using fft is $O(n\cdot \log(n))$.

The naive square matrix multiplication implementation is $O(n^3)$, maybe we can map the elements from a matrix to a polynomial (maybe multivariate) something like this:

$
\begin{bmatrix}ax&b\\cxy&dy\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}e&fz\\gx&hxz\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}(ae+bg)x&(af+bh)xz\\(ce+dg)xy&(cf+dh)xyz\end{bmatrix}
$

multiplying the polynomial:

$ (ax+b+cxy+dy)(e+fz+gx+hxz) = 
(aex+afxz+agx^2+ahx^2z)+(be+bfz+bgx+bhxz)+(cexy+cfxyz+cgx^2y+chx^2yz)+(dey+dfyz+dgxy+dhxyz)
$

simplifying:
$
(ae+gb)x+agx^2+ahx^2z+be+bfz+(af+bh)xz+(ce+dg)xy
+(cf+dh)xyz+cgx^2y+chx^2y+dey+dfyz$

removing all terms except terms with $x$:
$(ae+gb)x+(af+hb)xz+(ce+dg)xy+(cf+dh)xzy$

Can this be generalized for other cases? Using fft the complexity should be $O(n\cdot \log(n))$ or the tree variables increase the complexity?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How could it be $n\log(n)$? There is an obvious lower bound of $n^2$

Comment: Hi, yes using classic multiplication is $O(n^2)$. But using fft https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764727/concrete-fft-polynomial-multiplication-example have $O(n . log(n))$

Comment: Yes, multiplying two polynomials is $n\log n$. But you seem to be making the claim / speculation about matrix multiplication, which has a lower bound of $n^2$ (and as you note a naive upper bound of $n^3$). Perhaps you mean $n^2\log(n)$?

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm speculating. I'm very noob to this. I'm not clear hot to get to $n^2 log(n)$

Comment: My point was just that it needs to be bigger than $n^2$ since that’s the lower bound just based on touching all the data. I was saying maybe you meant $n^2\log(n)$ cause it conforms to that bound and it seemed like the kind of result one might naively expect the approach you are pitching to lead to. I’m not an expert, but as I understand it, there is no $n^2\log(n)$ algorithm known and finding one would be sort of a holy grail. So you can bet if a simple approach could do that, it would be found already. I’m not sure if fft has been found useful for this problem or not.

Comment: Make sense now thanks.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307321.pdf