# efficient way of calculating the $n-1$ polynomial coefficients

Tags: polynomials, fourier-transform, symmetric-polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

Given $n$ polynomials with the same $M$ degree.
$$
A_1 = \sum_{i=0}^M a_{1i} x^i \\
A_2 = \sum_{i=0}^M a_{2i} x^i \\
\cdots \\
A_n =\sum_{i=0}^M a_{ni} x^i 
$$

My objective is to obtain all coefficients from $n-1$ products, e.g.:
$$
N = \{1, \dots, n\}, 
\forall i \in N \\
\prod_{j \in N \setminus \{i\}} A_j
$$

One way I'm thinking is to get $\prod_{j \in N } A_j$ first using FFT, and perform $n$ Polynomial Division to obtain the final results. And I'm wondering if there are much better solutions around?

Another solution:

Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680697/1327967)

One can generate two sequence:

$$
B = 1, A_1A_2, A_1A_2A_3, \cdots, A_1A_2\cdots A_{n-1} \\
C = A_2\cdots A_{n-1}, A_3\cdots A_{n-1}, \cdots,  A_{n-2}A_{n-1}, 1
$$
And the result would be the pointwise product of $B$ and $C$

Comment: FFT by evaluating the product at the $3M$ roots of unity should directly give you all of the coefficients.

Comment: thanks for the interest! can you elaborate? as i would be interested in all the $M \times M$ coefficients.  not sure why would $3M$ roots of unity achieve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concrete FFT polynomial multiplication example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764727/concrete-fft-polynomial-multiplication-example)

Comment: Misread, the resulting polynomial is of degree $MN$. Generalizing to multiple products is the same with more $0$-padded terms IIRC.

Comment: I’m not sure why would that answer my questions, I have n different n-1 product of polynomials

Comment: It is the same with multiple polynomials, the coefficients are given by $$\mathcal F^{-1}(\mathcal F(\mathbf a_1)\mathcal F(\mathbf a_2)\dots\mathcal F(\mathbf a_n))$$ i.e. the inverse FFT of the element-wise vector products of all of their FFTs (once you add sufficiently many $0$'s to each).

Comment: Yeah, but the objective is to do $N$ different times of this, our goal is to get all ${N \choose N-1}$ products, $\mathcal F^{-1}(\mathcal F(\mathbf a_1)\mathcal F(\mathbf a_2)\dots\mathcal F(\mathbf a_n))$ would only provide one set of coefficient

Comment: btw, there is no $\mathbf  a_1$ in the question, there is only $\mathbf  a_{1i}$ from $\mathbf  A_1$

Comment: Ah I see. One quick way to get all of these products is to walk left and right once. That is to say, split each product into $\prod_{j<i}$ and $\prod_{j>i}$ for each $i$. By walking left and right, you can quickly build these two for all $i$, and then multiply them together once.

Comment: right, that is basically the second solution I shared in the question.

Comment: I'm referring to $\mathbf a_i$ as the $0$-padded vector of the coefficients as was written in the link.

Comment: I see now what you meant at the end. But I'm referring to multiplying the FFT vectors instead of the polynomials themselves because it's much easier to handle those.

Comment: yeah, but to maintain the FFT vectors is a bit tricky, as i can't just pad 0s to the left only for all polynomials, also some right hand 0 is needed to align the order between results of the product.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you only have to pad $0$'s on one side before taking the FFT like in the linked post.

Comment: $F^{-1}((F(A_1,0,0,0)F(A_2,0,0,0)) F(A_3,0,0,0))$ would produce a wrong result. The correct should be $F^{-1}((F(A_1,0,0,0,0,0,0)F(A_2,0,0,0,0,0,0))F(0,0,0,A_3,0,0,0))$

Comment: I'm not sure why you're padding the left side of $A_3$. Doing so changes the result from $A_1A_2A_3$ to $x^3A_1A_2A_3$.

Comment: $A_1A_2$ would produce a higher degree of polynomials than $A_3$, to reflect that, i need to pad 0s on the right for $A_3$ as well.  $F^{-1}(F(F^{-1}(F(A_1,0,0,0)F(A_2,0,0,0)),0,0,0)F(0,0,0,A_3,0,0,0))$

Comment: Yes, you only pad $0$'s on the right of $A_3$. Padding $0$'s on the left of $A_3$ changes the results completely, which is not what you wanted. There's also no need to repeatedly pad more or less $0$'s as you go. You only pad $0$'s to everything at the start so that each vector is at least as long as the final result.

Comment: ah sorry, you are right